# Harmonic function such that $u =\partial_\nu u = 0$ on a surface must vanish.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I'm studying problems from some qualifiers and I came across a problem I couldn't solve:

> Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a domain and suppose that $\Sigma\subseteq \Omega$ is a smooth (nontrivial) surface. If $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ is harmonic (i.e. $\Delta u = 0$ in $\omega$) and $u = \partial_\nu u = 0$ on $\Sigma$ then u vanishes identically.

Here, $\partial_\nu u = \nabla u\cdot \nu$ where $\nu$ is the normal vector.

Below is the solution I came up with and my questions about said solution.

Let $x_0\in \Sigma$ and $r>0$ be such that $B(x_0, r) \subseteq \Omega$ is devided by $\Sigma$ into two "side". We call these sides $\Omega_L$ and $\Omega_R$.

> While it feels intuitively clear that I can do this, how to I justify the existence of such a ball?

Now, define $\tilde{u} : B(x_0, r) \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\tilde{u}(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x\in \Omega_L\\
u(x) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
We claim that $\tilde{u}$ is harmonic. It would then follow from analiticity that $u \equiv \tilde{u} \equiv 0$.

Observe first that $\tilde{u}\in C\left(\overline{B(x_0, r)}\right)$. It therefore suffices to show that for all $x\in B(x_0, r)$
$$
\int\limits_{\partial B(x, \delta)}\partial_\nu \tilde{u} = 0
$$
for all sufficiently small $\delta > 0$.

> I am looking for a reference on this last result (if this is true!).

Since $u$ is harmonic, this is trivial unless $x\in\Sigma$. In this case, observe that
$$
\begin{split}
\int\limits_{\partial B(x, \delta)}\partial_\nu \tilde{u} 
&= \int\limits_{\partial \left[B(x, \delta)\cap \Omega_L\right]}\partial_\nu \tilde{u} + \int\limits_{\partial \left[B(x, \delta)\cap \Omega_R\right]}\partial_\nu \tilde{u} \\
&=\int\limits_{\partial \left[B(x, \delta)\cap \Omega_R\right]}\partial_\nu u\\ 
& = 0
\end{split}
$$
since $u$ is harmonic and the boundary of $B(x, \delta)\cap \Omega_R$ is piecewise smooth.

Comment: Explore what the maximum value theorem gives you for $u$ and $-u$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? The domain is not assumed to be bounded and $\Sigma$ is not on the boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: My mistake @Quoka, I mistook $\Sigma$ for the boundary. This is a nice problem!

Comment: I think that maybe these links can be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523716/harmonic-function-vanishes-with-its-normal-derivative-on-a-part-of-boundary-can https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482576/a-pde-exercise-from-gilbarg-trudinger-problem-2-2/483618#483618

Comment: @Quoka I know, but maybe you can try to adapt the ideas (?)