# Laplace equations with bad choices of boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Consider the Laplace equation over a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary:

$-\Delta u = 0$.

This equation has a solution space of infinite dimension if $n > 1$.
Now let $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_n$ be subsets of the boundary, say,
smooth submanifolds of $\partial\Omega$.
We consider the homogeneous boundary conditions

$u = 0$ along $\Gamma_{0}$ (vanishing function values)

$\partial_n u = 0$ along $\Gamma_{n}$ (vanishing normal derivative)

The Laplace equation with these two boundary conditions is well-understood if

- $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_n$ are disjoint and essentially cover the whole boundary of $\partial\Omega$. Then the solution space has dimension one or zero.

But what if

- $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_n$ are disjoint but do not cover the boundary?
  Then there is a free boundary part where no boundary conditions are imposed.
- $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_n$ cover the boundary but are not disjoint? 
  Then the boundary values seem to be overdetermined.
- $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_n$ have no restrictions?

I am particularly interested in which of these cases still allows 
for an infinite-dimensional space of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_n$ are disjoint but do not cover the boundary

Then the set of solutions is infinite, because one can prescribe some values on the free boundary part, reducing this to a standard mixed boundary vvalue problem. There is an infinite-dimensional space of possible boundary values.

- $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_n$  are not disjoint

By this I understand that their intersection contains a relatively open subset of the boundary. Then the problem is overdetermined, regardless of whether $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_n$  cover the entire boundary. No matter how small an open subset of $\partial \Omega$ is, prescribing both the values and normal derivative on that set allows for at most one harmonic function: see [A PDE exercise from Gilbarg Trudinger. problem 2.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482576). Hence, the boundary data would have to be very special to be consistent.

(Looks like all cases are covered by the above)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, my implicit assumption was that their intersection could be a relatively open subset, nothing too pathological.